# Encountering a Tkinter GUI error when calling 'filedialog.askdirectory(multiple=True)'

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

According to this webisite, [Tkinter Dialogs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html), I should be able to include 'multiple=True' in the function tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory(**options). I want the user of the GUI I am creating in Python to be able to select more than one folder at a time.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox

# Function to add folder to the base_list
def add_base_folder():
    initial_dir = r"C:\P&G LA VA 23 NNIT"
    folder = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir=initial_dir, multiple=True)

    if folder:
        if folder in selected_folders:
            messagebox.showinfo("Duplicate Folder", "Folder path already selected.")
        else:
            base_list.insert(tk.END, folder)
            selected_folders.add(folder)
            base_label.destroy()
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\commondialog.py", line 45, in shows = master.tk.call(self.command, *master._options(self.options))_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-multiple": must be -initialdir, -mustexist, -parent, or -title
```

My code works perfectly fine without the 'multiple=True', so I know that is the issue. But, I am wondering why the Tkinter Dialog documentation page is saying I can do something I clearly cannot.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know. I get the same error but it appears that `multiple=True` worked recently, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75884759/20948146).

Answer (score 1):

`multiple` is not a valid argument for `askdirectory`, just as the error states. You can confirm this by looking at the tkinter source code to see that it is just a wrapper around `tk_chooseDirectory`, and by looking at the canonical tk documentation for [tk_chooseDirectory](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.13/TkCmd/chooseDirectory.htm)

I think the official tkinter docs are just a little bit sloppy in how it presents the available options.